# Combining Two Pandas Series gives TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine two pandas series, values from one dataset need to be added to another one.
I am getting an error so I have prepared a simple test case following documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine.html

This is what I have tried:

```
s1 = pd.Series({'falcon': 330.0, 'eagle': 160.0})    
s2 = pd.Series({'falcon': 345.0, 'eagle': 200.0, 'duck': 30.0})    
s1.combine(s2, max)        ​
```

This is what I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-209-2133be1dc899> in <module>
      1 s1 = pd.Series({'falcon': 330.0, 'eagle': 160.0})
      2 s2 = pd.Series({'falcon': 345.0, 'eagle': 200.0, 'duck': 30.0})
----> 3 s1.combine(s2, max)

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in combine(self, other, func, fill_value)
   2546                 rv = other.get(idx, fill_value)
   2547                 with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 2548                     new_values.append(func(lv, rv))
   2549         else:
   2550             # Assume that other is a scalar, so apply the function for

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I guess that I am missing something. This is the Pandas version I am using:

```
'0.24.2'
```

Comment: Do you have a DataFrame named `max`?

Comment: I think that is it instead, yes @dani

Comment: @DaniMesejo - it is `combine`, not `combine_first`. For me working nice

Comment: It might be the case that I did something like that, I restarted the Jupyter notebook and it works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have reused the code you have written here additionally with the import line as well:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series({'falcon': 330.0, 'eagle': 160.0})    
s2 = pd.Series({'falcon': 345.0, 'eagle': 200.0, 'duck': 30.0})    
s1.combine(s2, max)
```

Here is the result:

```
duck        NaN
eagle     200.0
falcon    345.0
dtype: float64
```

I am using pandas version 0.24.2 so the only difference is maybe the import line that you are missing?

Comment: See comments, problem was located with an existing DataFrame.